# If I format a CD like a USB, can I still reformat it to burn it as an mp3 CD?

Tags: windows-7, windows, usb, mp3, compact-disc

I formatted a CD like a USB through Windows 7 auto play and filled it up with .mp3 files. Unfortunately the CD didn't play in my van. Is it possible to reformat the disc and burn it as an mp3 CD instead so that it would work in the van? The van can play .mp3 format...

I thought that any cd player that supports .mp3 format should be able to read .mp3 files like that?

Comment: What do you mean you formatted a CD like an USB?

Comment: In windows, when you insert a blank CD the autoplay window pops up. It gives you 2 options: **1)** Burn an audio disc (regular 80 minute CD style) **2)** Burn a file disc. For the 2nd option, you can choose to burn it like a USB where the CD uses a filesystem similar to a USB. This means that you can move/remove files on the CD at anytime.

Comment: Did you use a CD/RW?  Did you close the session on the CD.  Most non-computers can not play a CD if the session is not closed.

Comment: Hmm I didn't notice if it was CD/RW but I assume it is if it gave me the option to "burn like a USB". I'm not sure about closing the session and I never heard of that, although I haven't burned a CD in forever.. that could possibly be it? How do I close the session? I thought it was safe to assume once it was done writing files to the CD, and the CD slowed down reading/spinning that it was okay to eject and use..?

Answer (score 3):

You need to finalize the disc (therefore not allowing more content to be added, nor any removed)

Click the start menu, then select computer to open Windows Explorer.

Put the disc in the DVD drive, and now in Windows Explorer click the disc burner drive and then click Close session on the toolbar.

Comment: I'm curious if I close the session am I able to reopen it to edit the files later, which was the point of putting it in "USB mode" anyways?

Comment: No. This will close the disc off  .. so sadly you need to choose what you want, have it so you can amend comment or have it play in the van...

Answer (score 3):

Most of the old generation mp3 players don't recognize the UDF format (that got written to the cd when you selected "format like an USB drive" in windows) only the normal Data CD (this will be recognized by all mp3 CD players) or Audio CD (this won't let you burn mp3s, but only 80 mins of audio files and it will be recognized even by the oldest cd players that don't support mp3s).

Now, back to your problem, if the CD was a CD-RW one you can re-burn it with the normal Data CD and it will work (note: you have to check the cd to see if it's RW, the option to use it as an USB drive also appears for CD-R (not rewritable)) but if the CD was not ReWritable but CD-R (most likely) then you can't really do anything to make it work again in the mp3 player, the cd will only be usable in PCs with WindowsXP and higher.

Source and more details:
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/which-cd-dvd-format

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the disc icon (in my computer), then choose "erase disc". This way you will be directed back to the choice "USB disc" or "Audio CD". Hope this helps